# google chrome transition jumpy

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, google-chrome

I'm having trouble with jumpy css3 transforms. The animation is really jumpy on google chrome while internet explorer or firefox has no issues:

```css
   div {
     background-image: url("https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2014/02/23/11/11/strawberries-272812_640.jpg");
     height: 500px;
     width: 500px;
     background-position: center;
     transition: 0.5s all;
   }
   div:hover {
     transform: scale(1.3);
   }
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

(Also in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dsLawzo4/2/))

Don't know why but while putting up my code on jsfiddle I didn't have the issue.

PS: forgot to mention that I'm using bootstrap.

Comment: which version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: @cuadraman version 45.0.2454.101 m

Comment: Try adding `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0j1me71m/

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith Thanks for your time but it's not working. Still got the same issue. :(